# Populate Datagridview from different tables c#

Tags: c#, datagridview

I am try to populate a datagridview from 2 different tables which is nonMember and customer with this codes below... but the datagridview doesn't display anything except for a gray background.

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
        using (SqlCommand cmd = connection.CreateCommand())
        {
            connection.Open();
            cmd.CommandText = "@SELECT tbl_nonMember.*, tbl_customer.customerID AS Expr1, tbl_customer.lname, tbl_customer.fname, tbl_customer.mname, tbl_customer.gender, tbl_customer.age, tbl_customer.membership_type FROM tbl_customer INNER JOIN tbl_nonMember ON tbl_customer.customerID = tbl_nonMember.customerID";
            SqlDataAdapter adap = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            adap.Fill(ds);
            dataGridView2.DataSource = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;
        }
```

Comment: Do you have your DataGridView set to auto generate columns?

Comment: not yet, I can't find the auto generate columns in the DataGridView properties..

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this to your method before you set the datasource of dataGridView2.

```
dataGridView2.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
```

And your select query should not have @ in the front of the keyword SELECT. It should be:

```
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT tbl_nonMember.*, tbl_customer.customerID AS Expr1, tbl_customer.lname, tbl_customer.fname, tbl_customer.mname, tbl_customer.gender, tbl_customer.age, tbl_customer.membership_type FROM tbl_customer INNER JOIN tbl_nonMember ON tbl_customer.customerID = tbl_nonMember.customerID";
```

So I would venture to guess that after auto generating your columns, your Tables[0] did not return any rows because of the invalid select clause.

Comment: done adding this code, but it still displays gray datagridview